# python function is not working

Tags: python, list

Can somebody help me? I am trying to make that each char should be 'x'. It is not working! 
I have created a function which (suppously) should return xxx.. For exmaple if i put 'hello' on list, i want this function to return 'xxxxx'.

```
def encriptar(lletra):
    lletra = 'x'
    return lletra

letra = [input("Introduce la cadena: ")]
x=0

for x in range(0,len(letra)):
    letra[x]=encriptar(letra[x])
    print(letra[x])
    x+=1

print(letra)
```

Comment: Do you have a question or a doubt?

Comment: `print ('x' * len(input("Enter word ")))`. One of possible ways to attain.

Comment: I don't think this has an effect, but a for loop handles updating x, you don't need to increment it yourself in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On problem is that `letra = [input("Introduce la cadena: ")]` does not return what you expect. You get a list of one single element which is a string. And anyway a string is non mutable in Python.

A quick and simple fix would be to convert the string to a list of characters:

```
letra = list(input("Introduce la cadena: "))
```

Because now you have a mutable list and can replace each character in it:

```
for x in range(0,len(letra)):
    letra[x]=encriptar(letra[x])
    print(letra[x])
```

And you just have to join it before printing:

```
print(''.join(letra))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting user input as a string, and iterating over that, you're putting the string of user input into a list and iterating over that.

```
letra = [input("Introduce la cadena: ")]
```

If the user types `hello`, this means you end up with `letra` set to `["hello"]`. That is, a list of 1 item, where that item is a string. You therefore pass the whole string to `encriptar` instead of a single character at a time.

Instead, do:

```
letra = input("Introduce la cadena: ")
```

You'll then run into the problem that strings are *immutable*, so you'll need to construct a new string rather than updating the existing one in place.

You can easily construct a list of characters using a list comprehension:

```
new_chars = [
    encriptar(c)
    for c in letra
]
```

And then create a new string from that list:

```
letra = "".join(new_chars)
```